# Изменить формат даты, MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mariadb

Имеется огромная база данных в которой присутствует столбец с датой, дата формата 202001, 202002, 202003 .... 202101, 202102 и так далее. Формат у даты [год][номер месяца].
Мне необходимо перевести данный в адекватный вид, а конкретно изменить тип ячейки с varchar на datatime и изменить вид на 2020-01-01, 2020-02-01 и т.д [год-месяц-день]. Возможно ли реализовать подобное средствами mysql?

Проще было бы это сделать простой заменой, но даже notepad++ не тянет файлы с 100+ миллионов строк.

Comment: Можно строковыми функциями: ```CONCAT_WS('-', LEFT(column, 4), RIGHT(column, 2), '01')```. Можно и просто `column * 100 + 1`. Оптимум зависит от типа данных поля, наверное (надо тестировать). Но в любом случае контекст исполнения должен быть DATE.

Comment: *дата формата 202001* - это НЕ дата. Дата в обязательном порядке содержит все три компонента.

Comment: @Akina Нет, это именно дата в формате [год][месяц]. Я и задал этот вопрос, чтобы узнать, есть ли возможность перевести дату формата varchar в формат datatime.

Comment: *Нет, это именно дата в формате [год][месяц].* Ты можешь интерпретировать это как угодно - как дату, как температуру, как что-то ещё... Но объективно это НЕ дата. В любом случае ответ дан. Да, конвертация из VARCHAR в DATE вторым способом где-то в полтора раза быстрее. Но на большом объёме данных разницы не будет.

Comment: Вы понимаете для чего я задаю этот вопрос? Я указываю на то, что varchar !== data, но в строке содержится дата и мне её необходимо перевести в другой формат.

Comment: Я - понимаю. Вы - ни хрена не понимаете. MySQL автоматически преобразует типы данных в зависимости от контекста операции.

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL для этого есть встроенная функция: `STR_TO_DATE()`.

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/J_6jDWEm)

**SQL**

```
create table tbl (ID INT, bogusdate VARCHAR(10));
insert into tbl values 
(1, '202001'),
(2, '202102');

select *, CONCAT(bogusdate, '01') as JustToSee
    , STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(bogusdate, '01'),'%Y%m%d') as realdate
from tbl;
```

**Результат**

| ID | bogusdate | JustToSee | realdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202001 | 20200101 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 202102 | 20210201 | 2021-02-01 |

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, ym VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '202001'), (2, '202102');
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | ym |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 202001 |
| 2 | 202102 |

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN d DATE;
UPDATE test SET d = ym * 100 + 1;
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | ym | d |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202001 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 202102 | 2021-02-01 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IHsuYxg2)